# Maps between simplicial manifolds

Tags: simplicial-stuff, generalized-smooth-spaces, differentiable-stacks

Is it true that every continuous simplicial map between smooth simplicial manifolds can be approximate (in some adequate sense) by a smooth simplicial map?